# How do i run findbugs on specific package ignore other packages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

My project having multiple packages but i need to run **findbugs** on only specific package ignore other packages in eclipse.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You should describe the organization of your project.

Comment: Suppose in my java project having two packages like org.test.imf.* and org.test.iag. But we need to findbugs in org.test.imf.* not require for other packages.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more info like jww indicated would be helpul.

1. You use eclipse and the eclipse findbugs plugin, correct? (Which eclipse version, wich findbugs/SpotBugs version?)
2. Or do you use the maven plugin?

For eclipse you have two options:
Right click in the package explorer (only) the 'org.test.imf' package and in pop-up menu chose 'Find Bugs -> Find Bugs'.

The 2nd option is to define an exclusion filter in the plugin settings (Preferences\Findbugs\Filter files\Exclude filter files). How to define a filter is described [here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html). The XML file would look something like this (untested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Package name="org.test.iag.*"/>
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```